# Are there a way with XPath in lxml for getting TEXT in chain of unknown tags <tag1>...<tagn>TEXT</tagn>...</tag1>

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have a set of Elements (from lxml) with a linear html-chain of unknown tags like this:

```
<tag1>...<tagn>TEXT</tagn>...</tag1>
```

How could I use xpath to get the TEXT?

I mean, if my element is elem, I could use:
elem.xpath('XPATH')

What will be XPATH?

Comment: What have you tried already? Share your current XPath

Comment: If you don't know the tag names, and you don't know how many there will be, I'm not sure xpath is the right solution.

Comment: I got it. The solution is: elem.xpath('.//text()')

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the position, skip everything until you found text:

```
elem.xpath('.//text()')
```

Comment: It still not clear what is your issue, but this will just return *all* the text nodes.

Comment: I specify in the question the format I'm interested in. Its clear that there is only one TEXT.